# Why do we need to specify init method?

Tags: swift, swift2

The following block of code runs fine even without specifying the **init**     method. If this is the case, what purpose does the **init** method serve?

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

}

let somePerson = Person(name: "Sam", age: 21)
somePerson.name
somePerson.age
```

Thank you your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It's the behavior of Struct in swift.

See (Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types) in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

> "Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer if
>   they do not define any of their own custom initializers. Unlike a
>   default initializer, the structure receives a memberwise initializer
>   even if it has stored properties that do not have default values."

If you do not specify any memberwise init method, it will create for you. The init that you declare allow you to do more than just an simple init. For example:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int){
        self.name = name.uppercaseString()
        self.age = age + 22
        //and more works ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in this doc

[Swift initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

> Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or class that
>   provides default values for all of its properties and does not provide
>   at least one initializer itself. The default initializer simply
>   creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their default
>   values.
>
> Structure types automatically receive a memberwise initializer if they do not 
>   define any of their own custom initializers. Unlike a default
>   initializer, the structure receives a memberwise initializer even if
>   it has stored properties that do not have default values.

So if you write one init method, then you MUST write the default initializer yourself, if you want it to exist.

If you only need the default initializer, then you can omit it.

Comment: ... *that provides default values* is actually not the case in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it (anymore). Memberwise initialization is a new feature of Swift 2.2. The author either wrote this code for an earlier version of Swift or didn't know that it's no longer necessary.